# WFLYCTL0184: New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: webservice endpoint as an ejb that consume jms message on EAP 7

Tags: cxf, jax-ws, ejb-3.0, redhat, jboss-eap-7

I am deploying webservice endpoint as an ejb that consume jms message but I face the below exception:

```
 14:37:49,034 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8)     MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "mbv-fpdistributionservices-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: targetDestination may not be null
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:375)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:79)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:255)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:543)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.BusHolder.configure(BusHolder.java:234)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:97)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:59)
at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:73)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
... 5 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: targetDestination may not be null
at org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConfiguration.ensureProperlyConfigured(JMSConfiguration.java:105)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSDestination.activate(JMSDestination.java:104)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:53)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBindingFactory.java:95)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.addListener(SoapBindingFactory.java:895)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:123)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:366)

WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.CreateOrderServiceBean.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.CreateOrderServiceBean.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.CreateOrderServiceBean.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".WeldStartService, service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformation (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.CreateOrderServiceBean.START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".WeldBootstrapService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".CdiValidatorFactoryService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".CdiValidatorFactoryService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".WeldStartService] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.CreateOrderServiceBean (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.CreateOrderServiceBean.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.TaktEventOutServiceBean (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.TaktEventOutServiceBean.env."com.daimler.gepard.server.ejb.bean.TaktEventOutServiceBean".myDataSource (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ejb.jar".component.TaktEventOutServiceBean.START]
```

WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."mbv-fpdistributionservices-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."mbv-fpdistributionservices-war.war".INSTALL

below is a snippet from the endpoint code

```
@Stateless
@WebService(serviceName = "TaktEventOut",
                  portName = "TaktEventOutJMSEndpoint",
                  targetNamespace     "http://www.daimler.com/gepard/Service/PoC/TaktEventOut-001.wsdl",
                  wsdlLocation = "WEB- INF/wsdl/gepard/Service/PoC/TaktEventOut/TaktEventOut-001.wsdl",
                  endpointInterface = "com.daimler.gepard.service.poc.takteventoutabstract_001_wsdl.TaktEventOutPortType")
public class TaktEventOutJMSEndpointImpl implements TaktEventOutPortType, Serializable {

private static final QName FPDATA_SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://www.daimler.com/gepard/Service/PoC/FPData-001.wsdl", "FPData");
/** Default value included to remove warning. **/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@EJB
private CreateOrderService createOrderService;

OrderDTO orderDTO = new OrderDTO();

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TaktEventOutJMSEndpointImpl.class.getName());


public TaktEventOutJMSEndpointImpl() {

}
```

Comment: Don't you have an ERROR before this log entry which actually says what component it cannot find?

Comment: you are right :) I will update the error